# How to get the data between two dates byusing like command?

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

in My table i have 3 columns like Date,Name,client id and tese data types are date,varchar(50),varchar(50) respectively. iwant to search the records with From Date,To Date,Name,client id.when i write the procedure

```
create procedure credits_search
(
    @date1 date,@date2 date,@client_id varchar(50),@name varchar(50)
)
as
begin
select * from credits where date like between @date1 and @date2 or client_id like @client_id or name like @name
end
```

but iam getting error pls help me

Answer (score 0):

use the below query

select * from credits where date between @date1 and @date2 or client_id like '%'+ @client_id or name like '%'+ @name

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE credits_search
@dateFrom DATE,
@dateTo DATE,
@client_id varchar(50),
@name varchar(50)
AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    credits
WHERE
    date BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo OR
    client_id LIKE '%' + @client_id + '%' OR
    name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
```

I would suspect you are passing through DateTime to the query not just the Date. So change the dataTypes of your parameters to DATETIME.

```
@dateFrom DATETIME,
@dateTo DATETIME,
```

Comment: its execute in sqlserver properly ,but wheni run with my asp.net controls it raise this error  Procedure or function 'credits_search' expects parameter '@date1', which was not supplied.

Comment: can you supply the code in which you use the procedure

Comment: luke,i gave 3 conrols in my aspx page.i.e. from date & to date,Name,Client id.when we enter any text in these 3 fields we get the data from DB.that is my reqvirement.

Comment: So you use textbox to input date?

Comment: this is method for sending values toSppublic DataSet credits_search()
         {
             cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", this.Fromdate);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", this.Todatesearch);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", this.clientid);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", this.name);
             return (dblogic.databaselogic.showgrid(cmd, "credits_search"));
         }

Comment: and .cs code is if (txtcresearchfrom.Text != "" || txtcresearchto.Text != "")
        {
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtcresearchfrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            txtcresearchfrom.Text = dt1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtcresearchto.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            txtcresearchto.Text = dt2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            obj.Fromdate = dt1.ToString();
            obj.Todatesearch = dt2.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            txtcresearchfrom.Text = "";
            txtcresearchto.Text = "";

Comment: yes i use textboxes along with Ajax calendar exendar

Comment: string fromdate;
         string todatesearch;
         public string Fromdate
         {
             get { return this.fromdate; }
             set { this.fromdate = value; }
         }
         public string Todatesearch
         {
             get { return this.todatesearch; }
             set { this.todatesearch = value; }
         }

Comment: Is the date you are passing from your code in the same format of the dates in your database? They have to be the same.

Comment: acctually if i supply from date, to date values to txtboxes it will be executed,but my requirement is if i give only one value to any of these 3 control in aspx it get the mathced records from DB.

Comment: All the parameters need values. If you give dateFrom a value, give dateTo todays date. If you give DateTo a value, give dateFrom a date from like the beginning of the 1900s or something like that. So you need more validation in your .cs code to check if one is null or empty.